# Any Android phones that don't support Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth

Does anyone know of any current Android phones that do not have Bluetooth? We are trying to test our application on phones that do and don't support Bluetooth, but having a tough time finding any phones that don't have it.

Any pointers to sites that may help me track this down would be appreciated.

Comment: I would guess that you can't find that on the general marketplace but instead, on knock-off stores where they sell cheap and highly low-end phones just so people can have the "Android experience". Typically, those phones aren't even supported by Google and probably runs Froyo.

Comment: why do you want to spend time testing your app on a configuration that is so uncommon you can't even find it??? Put your efforts somewhere else :) !

Comment: @Stefano, answers here suggest that there may really be no non-Bluetooth phones to worry about, so you're right it may be a moot point. We are trying to set our app permissions to the minimum needed and wanted to test this combination.

Comment: @BrianC sounds like a wise choice :) !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably not a single one.

The reason is that initially (or still?) Google had requirements for handset makers if they wished to include the Google apps in their phone like: handset needs to include 3G, GPS, Bluetooth support (and probably more).

All recent phones will have bluetooth, so if you really find one without: It's probably outdated and runs on an old version of Android.

You might try an Amazon Kindle (that's really stripped down), but that has also no Google Apps, no GPS and no GSM and is a tablet.

Last resort if you really want to get one without bluetooth support:
Get a model with good CyanogenMod support and build your own ROM with bluetooth patched out (Seems like you do development, so you might consider this).

EDIT:

Here's the [Android Compatibility Definition Document](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/de//compatibility/android-cdd.pdf)

You might find more information here why every device nowadays has Bluetooth integrated:
Due to the Oracle America vs. Google lawsuit some of the contracts ("Mobile Application Distribution Agreement") between Google and handset manufacturers HTC and Samsung were published:

http://www.benedelman.org/docs/samsung-mada.pdf

http://www.benedelman.org/docs/htc-mada.pdf

Comment: GSMArena [lists several devices without Bluetooth](http://www.gsmarena.com/results.php3?sName=&idOS=8&idBluetooth=2), see [my answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/48233/16575) :)

Comment: @ce4 is there a place where I could read such requirements from Google?

Comment: They were secret initially however due to the Oracle America vs. Google lawsuit at least some of the "Mobile Application Distribution Agreement" contracts between Google & HTC and Google & Samsung have been published by the court: see the edited answer

Answer (score 3):

Due to no licensing cost and cheap hardware, its difficult to find a smartphone without bluetooth.

To test your application, you can disable bluetooth hardware in any rooted Android device. To do this, use [Hardware Disabler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hatcyl.android.Hardware_Disabler) app. But, make sure you have selected correct driver of bluetooth to disable. To find correct driver of bluetooth, you can either Google or find it using [Android Sensor Box](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=imoblife.androidsensorbox) app.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [phone finder @GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/search.php3). [These search results](http://www.gsmarena.com/results.php3?sName=&idOS=8&idBluetooth=2) give you a list of candidates with Android and no Bluetooth -- according to the data available at that site. I'm not 100% sure if some of the results are just listed because it is unknown to the site whether they support Bluetooth or not, but it at least gives you a good start.

Comment: Wasn't BT one of the requirements (besides gps) to get & ship the phone with Google Apps?

Comment: That might be -- but who said all Android devices ship with GApps installed? One example you gave yourself, mentioning Amazon's Kindle (which does not ship with GApps for "some other" reasons). Neither were GApps part of the question :)